# The gap size of floating point

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, numerical-linear-algebra, floating-point, computer-arithmetic

In Trefethen Bau Numerical Algebra, floating point set F is defined by

$\textbf{F} = \left\{\pm(m/\beta^{t})\beta ^{e}| 1 \leq m \leq \beta^{t}, e \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$

Equivalently, by making $m$ 1 to 1 correspond to each floating points,

$\textbf{F} = \left\{\pm(m/\beta^{t})\beta ^{e}| \beta^{t-1} \leq m \leq \beta^{t} - 1, e \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$

So, the gap size between each floating point I think is $\beta ^{e-t}$, which makes machine epsilon be $\frac{1} 2 \beta ^{-t}$ (because $1$ in F by the first definition is when $m = \beta ^{t}$ and $e = 0$).
And the second definition is telling that it is $\frac{1} 2 \beta ^{1-t}$, which corresponds to the definition of machine epsilon in the book. But the gap size is still unchanged.

**1. Other resources on the Internet told that the gap size of floating point is $\beta ^{1-t+e}$. What am I wrong?**

**2. Why are the machine epsilons obtained by each definition different?**

In first definition, there are many 1's by different m and e. Which one should I choose? Should I just use 2nd def?